# What is a word for trying to figure out how something was built?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for trying to figure out how something complicated was built? Trying to first figure out what the building blocks are and then work your way up to see how other more complicated pieces are built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To figuring out from the bottom up:  to **engineer**

Definition of engineer: [oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/engineer)

> ```
> 1 person who designs, builds, or maintains engines, machines, or structures.
>
> 1.1 A person qualified in a branch of engineering, especially as a professional.
> ‘an aeronautical engineer’
> ```
>
> 2 person who controls an engine, especially on an aircraft or ship.
>
> ```
> North American train driver.
> ```
>
> 3 skillful contriver or originator of something. ‘the prime engineer
>   of the approach’
>
> verb [with object]
>
> ```
> Design and build (a machine or structure)
> ‘the men who engineered the tunnel’
>
> Modify (an organism) by manipulating its genetic material.
> ‘it is now possible to engineer tobacco plants that are resistant to the virus’
> ```
>
> Skilfully arrange for (something) to occur. ‘she engineered another
>   meeting with him’

And to figure out from the top down: **reverse engineering** in English:  [oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reverse_engineering)

noun

> The reproduction of another manufacturer's product following detailed
>   examination of its construction or composition.

Comment: this is really close to what I need, except that reverse engineering has the implication that you are starting from the surface and working your way down to the building blocks. What I'm talking about is first find the building blocks and work your way up.

Comment: @user1068636 bottom up - or top down, I included both in my answer.

Comment: Typically "reverse engineering" is used.  It doesn't refer to top-down vs bottom-up, but rather working backwards, from the final product back to the principles that were used to build it.  (This is speaking as someone with a masters in EE who has employed reverse engineering several times.)

Comment: @HotLicks agree and initially answered as such but OP seemed confused so i attempted 'to make it simple'.

Comment: @user1068636: If this isn’t what you’re looking for, then you shouldn’t accept it. In general, it’s considered a bad idea to accept an answer in the first 24-48 hours after you’ve posted a question, because it discourages other users from answering. (Remember that [SE] has users around the world, in different time zones, and with different work schedules.) After two or three days, it’s OK to accept the best answer, even if it isn’t perfect, but don’t jump the gun.